# Redshift Spectrum partitioning a table using two date fields

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I was searching for best practices to create partitions by date, using `amazon-redshift-spectrum`, but the examples shows the problem being solved by partitioning the table by one date only. What to do if I have more than one date field?

Eg: Mobile events with `user_install_date` and `event_date`

How performative is to partition your `s3` like:

```
   installdate=2015-01-01/eventdate=2017-01-01
   installdate=2015-01-01/eventdate=2017-01-02
   installdate=2015-01-01/eventdate=2017-01-03
```

Will It kill my `select` performance ? What is the best strategy in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you data was partitioned in the above manner, then a query that merely had `eventdate` in the WHERE clause (without `installdate`) would be less efficient.

It would still need to look through every `installdate` directory, but it could skip over `eventdate` directories that do not match the predicate.

Put the less-used parameter second.